# ¿Cómo puedo insertar una tabla en una imagen?

Tags: python, imagen, dataframe, table

Quiero insertar una tabla en una imagen, utilice el siguiente código pero cuando la tabla se inserta en la imagen queda desalineada, como lo muestra la imagen adjunta.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 
import pandas as pd

dt =  {'column1':["AA","BBBB","CCC","DDDDD"],'column2':[143.40,144.60,153.40,92.50],'column3':[144.21,142.60,155.65,92.77]}

cuadro = pd.DataFrame(data=dt)
cuadro = cuadro.to_string(index= False,justify = 'center',col_space=16)


img = Image.open("image.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial",60)
draw.multiline_text((100, 400),cuadro,(255,255,255),font=font,align='center')
img.save('image.jpg')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

El desajuste de columnas está causado por la fuente que has usado para mostrarlo.

Cuando conviertes tu cuadro en una cadena, el resultado es la cadena siguiente:

```
"""
    column1           column2          column3    
         AA            143.4           144.21     
       BBBB            144.6           142.60     
        CCC            153.4           155.65     
      DDDDD             92.5            92.77   
"""
```

El cual se ve correctamente alineado porque la fuente que se usa por defecto en la consola es de **ancho fijo**, lo que significa que todos los caracteres tienen el mismo ancho, tanto los espacios, como la `A`, como la `l`.

En cambio en un tipo de letra como Arial, cada carácter tiene un ancho difernente. La A es mucho más ancha que la l, por poner un ejemplo, y esto rompe la alineación.

La solución más sencilla por tanto sería usar un tipo de letra de ancho fijo (*monospaced*). Cuál puedes usar depende de tu sistema. Ya que has usado Arial supongo que estás en un sistema Windows, por lo que puedes probar Courier New o Consolas. Yo he hecho una prueba en un ordenador con Linux y la fuente monoespaciada de que dispongo es "LiberationMono-Regular", y esto es lo que he intentado:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 
import pandas as pd

dt =  {'column1':["AA","BBBB","CCC","DDDDD"],'column2':[143.40,144.60,153.40,92.50],'column3':[144.21,142.60,155.65,92.77]}

cuadro = pd.DataFrame(data=dt)
cuadro = cuadro.to_string(index= False,justify = 'center',col_space=12)


img = Image.new('RGB', (800, 300), color = '#000080')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("LiberationMono-Regular",30)
draw.multiline_text((50, 40),cuadro,(255,255,255),font=font, align='center')
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Bonus. Solución *overkill*

La siguiente solución es "matar moscas a cañonazos", sobre todo por lo complejo del setup, pero no me he resistido a probarlo, y viendo que funciona, a incluirlo en la respuesta.

La idea es:

- Convertir el dataframe en HTML en vez de texto plano. Esto es sencillo con el método `DataFrame.to_html()`, aunque también habrá que escribir un css para darle algo de estilo.
- Convertir el HTML en imagen PNG con fondo transparente. Esto es sencillo si se tienen las herramientas apropiadas, pero instalar esas herramientas es la parte tediosa.

  Para empezar debe instalarse en el sistema la herramienta `wkhtmltopdf` (en linux disponible con `apt install` pero en Windows o en Mac es más complejo).

  Además, si estás en linux, debes tener Xwindow funcionando, o bien en su defecto instalar (con `apt install`) el software [xvfb](/questions/tagged/xvfb).

  Con todo esto instalado, es necesario el paquete python `imgkit` (`pip install`), y entonces una línea python hace la conversión de HTML a PNG, pero por debajo esa conversión aparentemente sencilla implica poner en marcha un navegador web *headless* (sin salida a pantalla) que usa el motor de renderizado Webkit (el mismo que usa Chrome) para "capturar" la pantalla virtual de ese "navegador" y así obtener el PNG.
- Finalmente superponer a tu imagen la imagen con la tabla generada en el paso anterior.

Todo junto:

```
# Esquema del "documento" que vamos a crear con la tabla

layout = """
<html><head>
  <style>
  .dataframe {
     font-family: "Liberation Sans", Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
     color: white;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     border: 1px solid grey;
  }
  .dataframe thead {
    background-color: #006080;
  }
  .dataframe th, td {
    padding: 5pt;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  %s    <!--  Aqui se inserta la tabla -->
</body>
</html>
"""

cuadro = layout % df.to_html(index=False)

import imgkit

# Guardar en un fichero png la imagen de la tabla anterior
imgkit.from_string(cuadro, "tabla.png", {"xvfb": "", "transparent": ""})

# Leer el fichero y pegarlo encima de nuestra imagen
img = Image.new('RGB', (800, 300), color = '#000080')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img_tabla = Image.open("tabla.png")
img.paste(img_tabla, (50, 40), img_tabla)
```

Y el resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Bonus 2: Otra solución más

Existe un paquete llamado [`dataframe_image`](https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image) que puedes instalar con `pip install`. Este paquete es capaz de convertir un dataframe pandas en una imagen, para lo cual prueba varias estrategias:

- Intenta crear la tabla con latex si está instalado
- Si no, intenta crear la tabla como HTML e invocar a chrome para que éste la convierta en png. Requiere tener chrome instalado
- Si lo prefieres, puedes pedirle que use matplotlib para crear la imagen de la tabla.

Hasta donde he mirado no resulta muy sencillo modificar los colores de la tabla, aunque seguramente sea posible con `pandas.DataFrame.style`, sólo que no estoy familiarizado con esto.

Este es un experimento que usa este paquete para primero convertir la tabla en png (usando el *backend* de `matplotlib`, pues la máquina en que probé no tenía LaTeX ni Chrome), y después pegar el resultado encima de otra imagen:

```
import dataframe_image as dfi
dfi.export(df, "mytable.png", table_conversion='matplotlib')

img = Image.new('RGB', (800, 300), color = '#000080')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img_tabla = Image.open("mytable.png")
img.paste(img_tabla, (50, 40), img_tabla)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]